# How to "fix zoom function" error in balkangraph orgchart?

Tags: charts, orgchart

When I initialize the balkan orgchart. Its fit on screen but i need to zoom out when its initialize. But its throwing error when i call zoom function with chart variable which i mentioned in code.

**chart.zoom(0.5)**

```
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
                        template: "rony",
                        nodeMouseClick: OrgChart.action.none,
                        mouseScrool: OrgChart.action.zoom,
                        align: OrgChart.ORIENTATION,
                        enableSearch: false,
                        showXScroll: OrgChart.none,
                        toolbar: {
                            zoom: true,
                            fit: true,
                            expandAll: false
                        },
                        collapse: {
                            level: 2,
                            allChildren: true
                        },
                        nodeBinding: {
                            field_0: "name",
                            field_1: "title",
                            field_2: "department",
                            img_0: "img",
                            field_number_children: "field_number_children"
                        },
                        nodes: nodes
                    });
```

I expect the output to zoom out the chart when its initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scaleInitial` option:

```
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
    scaleInitial: 0.5
});
```